# I am looking for a form builder that fully integrates with REST API and does not store any data

Tags: api, mobile, forms, rest, gui-builder

For our internal database system we are missing one piece of software which is a quickly deployable and relatively easy to configure form builder that does not store any data (besides some metadata and selection list values) but is fully able to integrate with our custom built REST API and that uses a mobile friendly approach.

In essence, the flow would ideally look something like this:

- Show objects on a list based on a custom API call we are able to
  configure.
- Clicking on an object in the list opens a custom form that got
  configured by ourselves.
- When completing the form, the input gets sent to the database using
  another of our custom REST API calls.

This would give us the ability to have all business logic outside of our own software and be able to handle changing requirements flexibely.

Have access control over which users get to see which forms. Ideally is able to integrate with MS/O365 SS0.

My preference goes to self hosted open source software.